# How to search for a file with a period in the name with Windows file search?

Tags: windows-search

How can I search for all files that contain a period somewhere in the file name but not count the period that comes before the file extension?

Examples I would want returned:

sky.blue.jpg

thesis.draft.txt

Any files that have a period within the main filename.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: press Win+s and enter the file name which you wish to search.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, what would be the search string to use to get the intended result? I tried  `*.*.`  but that isnt working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For advanced file searches, use the
[Advanced Query Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

For example, to search for files-names containing a dot in addition to the one
before the extension, use the following search term:
`filename:*.*.*`

Answer (score 0):

To search graphically press WIN+S and enter the file name which you wish to search for.

You and also use **cmd** to search for files
Press **WIN+R** and type cmd and hit enter.It will launch cmd.

Using **cd** go to the root of the directory and type

```
dir /s sky.blue.jpg
```

Here /s is for searching in sub-directories.This link will be usefull [searching through cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066679/how-to-do-a-simple-file-search-in-cmd).

Comment: Sorry i dont think you understand my question.  I am trying to understand which search syntax to use to return all files regardless of extension that have a period inside of the file name but not including the period before the file extension.

Comment: to search sky.blue.jpg use sky*